# Lack of recursive expansion in rule prerequisites

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that basically looks like this:

```
DIRS = a
all : $(DIRS)
DIRS += b
a b:
    @ echo $@
```

I was surprised to discover that only `a` gets printed. Why? I thought the whole advantage of recursive expansion was that I can expand my variables in arbitrary order for convenience. Is there a way to get the behavior I want for the prerequisites of `all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that make has *already* expanded `$(DIRS)` by the time you append to it.

From [3.7 How make Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles):

> GNU make does its work in two distinct phases. During the first phase it reads all the makefiles, included makefiles, etc. and internalizes all the variables and their values, implicit and explicit rules, and constructs a dependency graph of all the targets and their prerequisites. During the second phase, make uses these internal structures to determine what targets will need to be rebuilt and to invoke the rules necessary to do so.
>
> It’s important to understand this two-phase approach because it has a direct impact on how variable and function expansion happens; this is often a source of some confusion when writing makefiles. Here we will present a summary of the phases in which expansion happens for different constructs within the makefile. We say that expansion is immediate if it happens during the first phase: in this case make will expand any variables or functions in that section of a construct as the makefile is parsed. We say that expansion is deferred if expansion is not performed immediately. Expansion of a deferred construct is not performed until either the construct appears later in an immediate context, or until the second phase.
>
> ...
>
> **Rule Definition**
>
> A rule is always expanded the same way, regardless of the form:
>
> ```
> immediate : immediate ; deferred
>     deferred
> ```
>
> That is, the target and prerequisite sections are expanded immediately, and the recipe used to construct the target is always deferred. This general rule is true for explicit rules, pattern rules, suffix rules, static pattern rules, and simple prerequisite definitions.

You can always **add** prerequisites to targets.

So you could add `all: b` when you know what `b` is to add it to the prerequisite list for `all`.

You could also put `all:` at the top (for the default target selection) and then put `all: $(DIRS)` at the bottom to use the full `DIRS` value as prerequisites.

Lastly you could use [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) to force an extra expansion phase that should do what you want here.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
all: $$(DIRS)
```